# Python MSSQL dump to list

Tags: python, pymssql

I am grabbing data out of MS SQL via python via:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT IP FROM Nodes WHERE NodeGroup=%s', 'group1')
row = cursor.fetchall()

return row
```

I am receiving this as the return:

```
[('10.10.10.10',), ('10.10.10.20',), ('10.10.10.30',), ('10.10.10.40',)]
```

I need it to be in the format of:

```
['10.10.10.10', '10.10.10.20', '10.10.10.30', '10.10.10.40']
```

I'm assuming this is a tuple of tuples? How can I get the output I'm looking for from the .fetchall()?

Comment: `[x[0] for x in row]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn your tuples to a list

```
row = [ r[0] for r in cursor.fetchall() ]
```

Comment: So just iterate through the fetchall and make a new list? Worked just fine. Are there any speed concerns when returning a lot of rows?

Comment: Actually list comprehensions are a bit faster  than iterating over a for loop , but still this will be slower than just returning a list of tuples

Comment: Got it. The comprehension works great. Are there any other options for cursor other than fetchall() that would yield a better list? Meaning, give me the output I'm looking for but in a DB select instead of doing a comprehension or iteration?

Comment: I think you can get a dict with `cursor(as_dict=True)` , but i don't know if you can get a list ( i'm not that familiar with the `pymssql` lib ) . You can get more info [here](http://pymssql.org/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html#rows-as-dictionaries) if you find that useful